# How set different path to i18n resources for dev and production version application in Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

When i use my dev version of Angular application every paths are correct. But when i building my application to production version i deploying it on context /frontend/.

I want to change path to i18n resources (im using ngx-translate) only for production version of my app so I tried this command which im using to build app for production:

`"build-prod": "ng build --deploy-url /frontend/ --prod --base-href /frontend/",`

but its not working, my i18n resources in prod application is still searching on default path
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular's isDevMode() to give different paths for dev and prod. Example:

```js
export const createTranslateLoader = (http: HttpClient) => {
  const cacheBuster = new Date();
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(
    http,
    isDevMode() ? "/assets/i18n/" : "/frontend/assets/i18n/",
    ".json?cacheBuster=" + cacheBuster
  );
};
```